# Read data about specific element in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this list:

```
render() {
    return (
        <section className='display-question'>
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <ul style={{listStyleType: 'none'}}>
                    {/*kategoria, poziom (liceum itd), pkty, zdjecie*/}
                    {this.state.questions.map((question) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={question.id}>
                                <h3>Kategoria: {question.category}</h3>
                                <p>Poziom: {question.level}</p>
                                <p>Punkty: {question.pointAmount}</p>
                                <img alt='' style={{width: '20%'}} src={question.photoURL}/>
                                <Button onClick={this.clickHandler} style={{display: 'block', margin: 'auto'}}
                                        bsStyle="primary" id={question.id}>Rozwiaz to zadanie kurwo
                                </Button>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

I want, every time someone clicks on the button, it will take them to a different screen, showing more details. But I have no idea how to start. So far this is my `App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from "./components/nav";
import Questions from './components/questions';
import {Stuff} from './components/stuff';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(p) {
        super(p);
        this.state = {user: null};
        this.checkUserState = this.checkUserState.bind(this);
    }

    checkUserState(user) {
        this.setState({user});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Navbar {...this}/>
                {this.state.user ? <Questions/> : <Stuff/>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

And this is the `Questions.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

class Questions extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentItem: '',
            username: '',
            questions: []
        }
        this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const questionsRef = firebase.database().ref('Works');
        questionsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
            let questions = snapshot.val();
            let newState = [];
            for (let question in questions) {
                newState.push({
                    id: question,
                    category: questions[question].category,
                    level: questions[question].level,
                    pointAmount: questions[question].pointAmount,
                    photoURL: questions[question].photoURL,
                });
            }
            this.setState({
                questions: newState
            });
        });
    }

    clickHandler() {
        console.log("e");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className='display-question'>
                <div className='wrapper'>
                    <ul style={{listStyleType: 'none'}}>
                        {/*kategoria, poziom (liceum itd), pkty, zdjecie*/}
                        {this.state.questions.map((question) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={question.id}>
                                    <h3>Kategoria: {question.category}</h3>
                                    <p>Poziom: {question.level}</p>
                                    <p>Punkty: {question.pointAmount}</p>
                                    <img alt='' style={{width: '20%'}} src={question.photoURL}/>
                                    <Button onClick={this.clickHandler} style={{display: 'block', margin: 'auto'}}
                                            bsStyle="primary" id={question.id}>Rozwiaz to zadanie kurwo
                                    </Button>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

export default Questions;
```

And this is what I have for the `question.js` file.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Question extends React.Component {
    constructor(p) {
        super(p);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <img src="" alt=""/>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

So how this works: I grab the list from Firebase, then I render a list with h3, some ps, img, and a button.

I want when the button is clicked, for the user to be taken to a different "screen" with more details. But I cannot see how to set it up.

Any help will be appreciated. I'm open to another suggestions. I was thinking about making it a modal, but this doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece is that you don't use any routing library.

The most popular one is [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router).

Here's a basic example ([from their docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)), that will help you to understand the idea and help you start using it:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
)

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.path}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
    <Route exact path={match.path} render={() => (
      <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
)

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
export default BasicExample
```

Comment: Should I make the `Router` as it's own component?

Comment: I don't see any benefits from this. You can start defining your `<Route />` components in your top-level component, and if there's any reason later to move the definitions in a their own component, then I suggest you to do it. Also I'm suggestion you to start playing / looking at the docs, there's really good use-cases and examples: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: Ok this router is amazing. So easy to implement! Thank you!